# What's a good hash function for struct with 3 unsigned chars and an int, for unordered_map?

Tags: c++, unordered-map, hash-function

I just want to use a unordered_map with my struct as key, since I dont need any ordering..but I just cant find myself with all that hash stuff..

As a side relevant question..When ppl compare unordered and ordered map they never talk about the hash function, how can that be? Cant a bad hash function makes unordered map slower than map? (solely due the hash function)

```
struct exemple{

  unsigned char a,b,c;
  unsigned int n;

  bool operator == ( const exemple & other) const {..}
};

namespace std {
template <>
struct hash<exemple> : public std::unary_function<const exemple &, std::size_t>
{
    inline std::size_t operator()(const exemple & exemple_p ) const
    {
        return 0;// what do I do
    }
};
```

}

-edit-
a,b,c  can have only the values 'a', 'b', 'c' or 'd', and n varies ~ 3 to 60.

Comment: Are you required to write the hash function yourself?

Comment: These are two distinct questions. Please post one of them at a time.

Comment: @evanmcdonnal what do you mean? unordered map doesnt compile if I dont provide one.

Comment: Yes, but you could use the logic from a hashing library that already exists. As an example, say I have some string hashing function `hash(string)` I could make a function that converts the `int` to a string then concatenates it with the three `chars`, then end the function with `return hash(StringIjustMade);` which is different from actually writing the low level hashing logic yourself.

Comment: @evanmcdonnal would you post an answer showing it? I never used a hash function directly

Comment: First you drop `unary_function`. This stuff is officially useless since like forever.

Comment: @Icebone1000 I'm not going to because there are already two good solutions posted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you do in your hash function depends on the values you got, not necessarily so much on their types. If all four data members contain each value evenly distributed, I would combine the two characters into an `unsigned long` and return the result of xoring the two values:

```
typedef unsigned long ulong;
return n ^ (ulong(a << 16) | ulong(b << 8) | ulong(c));
```

It is certainly *a* hash function. Whether it is one which works well is a different question. You might also combine the result with `std::hash<unsigned long>`.

Comment: apropos combining hashes: Why has C++11 ommited `hash_combine`? It's a nice feature of `boost::hash`.

Comment: oh I see...I should mention then my unsigned chars can only asume a,b,c or d values...and n varies from ~3 to 60

Comment: Are you saying that you have 4<sup>3</sup>*60 ~= 2^<sup>12</sup> == 4096 values? In that case don't bother using a hash map but use an array...

Comment: @pmr: The only trace of `hash_combine` I can find is in [n3333](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2012/n3333.html). Put differently: you didn't propose it! Nor did anybody else.

Comment: std::hash<unsigned long> is giving me a conversion error, error C2440: '<function-style-cast>' : cannot convert from 'unsigned long' to 'std::hash<_Kty>'

Comment: I don't know what you are trying but it should work: `std::hash<unsigned long> hasher; unsigned long hash = hasher(value);`. From the looks of it, you try to pass the `unsigned long` as a constructor argument to `std::hash<unsigned long>`, i.e., `std::hash<unsigned long>(value)`. This, of course, doesn't work.

Comment: yep, that was exactly what I was doing

Answer (score 3):

Here's a baseline hash function:

```
unsigned long long h = (n << 24) | (a << 16) | (b << 8) | c;
return std::hash(h);
```

I.e., just pack the members into an `unsigned long long`, then offload the work to `std::hash`. In the common case that `int` is 32 bits wide and `long long` is 64 bits, and assuming your chars are not negative, this uses all the information in your objects for the hash.

Answer (score 2):

Consider your `struct` as a whole to be a string of bytes (7, to be precise).  You may use any acceptably general string hash function upon those 7 bytes.  Here is the FNV (Fowler/Noll/Vo) general bit-string hash function applied to your example (within the given hash functor class):

```
inline std::size_t operator()(const exemple& obj ) const
{
  const unsigned char* p = reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char*>( &obj );
  std::size_t h = 2166136261;

  for (unsigned int i = 0; i < sizeof(obj); ++i)
    h = (h * 16777619) ^ p[i];

  return h;
}
```

Note how I converted the reference to the `exemple` structure (`obj`) to a pointer to `const unsigned char` so that I could access the bytes of the structure one-by-one, and I treat it as an opaque binary object.  Note that `sizeof(obj)` may actually be 8 rather than 7 depending upon the compiler's padding (which would mean there's a garbage padding byte somewhere in the structure, probably between `c` and `n`.  If you wanted, you could rewrite the hash function to iterate over `a`, `b`, and `c` and then the bytes of `n` in order (or any order), which would eliminate the influence of any padding bytes (which may or may not exist) upon the hash of your `struct`.

Yes, a bad hash function can make `unordered_map` slower than `ordered_map`. This isn't always discussed, because generalized, fast algorithms like the FNV hash given above are assumed to be used by those using `unordered_map`, and in those cases, generally an `unordered_map` is faster than an `ordered_map` at the expense of the ability to iterate over the container's elements in order.  However, yes, you must being using a good hash function for your data, and usually it's good enough to use one of these well-known hashes.  Ultimately, however, every hash function has its weaknesses depending upon the input data's (here, the contents of the `exemple` structure) distribution.

A good discussion of generalized hashing and example hashing functions can be found at [Eternally Confuzzled](http://eternallyconfuzzled.com/tuts/algorithms/jsw_tut_hashing.aspx), including a C-style FNV hash similar to the one which I've given you.

Answer (score 1):

[`boost::hash_combine`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/doc/html/hash/combine.html) is designed for this purpose:

```
std::size_t hash = 0;
for (const auto& value : {a, b, c}) {
    boost::hash_combine(hash, value);
}
boost::hash_combine(hash, n);
return hash;
```